# Can you remove the time from UIDatePicker?

Tags: ios, uidatepicker

I'd like to use the uidatepicker (Date and Time mode) and display the day/month/date without the time.

Does anyone know to accomplish this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Set the `datePickerMode` to date. Here are the modes:

```
typedef enum {
   UIDatePickerModeTime,
   UIDatePickerModeDate,
   UIDatePickerModeDateAndTime,
   UIDatePickerModeCountDownTimer
} UIDatePickerMode;
```

Your question mentioned date and time mode without the time, that doesn't make any sense.

Comment: I want my date picker to display the day/month/day just like the  UIDatePickerModeDateAndTime for example: Tue Jun 24 (minus the time) The UIDatePickerModeDate displays month/date/year for example June 25 2014 Sorry I can't post images.

Comment: I understand. You should probably add that to your question, then. I don't think there's a built-in way to do that, without hiding the unwanted components in the picker or just writing your own datasource.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me.
Swift 5.4.2

```
 self.datePicker.datePickerMode = .date
```

Comment: This only hides the selectable time from the user, if you're to print `self.datePicker.date` then the exact time would still be printed.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was this line of code (Xcode12):

```
examDatePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePicker.Mode.date
```